# Is it ok to store a table saw outdoors in a crate?

Tags: outdoor, storage, table-saw

I recently purchased my first table saw - a Ridgid R4518 or similar model number. My only 'indoor' storage space is a small side shed that houses my water heater - it's very difficult to get the saw to fit through the door and I also have other items I want to store in there as well, and the table saw takes up too much room.

I recently purchased a few sheets of cheap (er, really expensive right now) plywood and built a crate with a swinging door that I keep under my car port. It shouldn't be hit by rain directly but might get some spray during heavy thunder storms. I plan to line the edges/corners with waterproof tape just in case, as well as wrap a tarp around it if there is severe weather incoming.

My question is - should I be concerned that this will cause long term issues with the table saw? Either due to condensation causing rust or something else? I live in the US southeast about 4 hours away from the ocean so I'm not concerned about salt, however it does still get very humid at times.

Comment: I would recommend checking out [woodworking.se]. There are quite a number of posts there about protecting tools from rust. You'll probably need all the help you can get for this particular storage scenario. Not to say you shouldn't have gotten the saw, just that you're going to need to take precautions, and it sounds like you're making a good start.

Comment: Although I agree with Isherwood I believe my rigid saw has a cast aluminum table, I have had to replace the motor when it got wet , but the table has not rusted.

Comment: I checked the home depot website and it looks like the table itself is made from cast aluminum, so I guess my main concern at this point would be rust in the motor. I am going to look at getting some desiccant material and look in to ways I can further prevent moisture from reaching the motor.

Comment: Most tables today, except in higher-end saws, are aluminum.  But the motor housing, shaft, and other associated parts are often steel or cast iron and these will tend to rust in any environment that allows moisture to collect on it, and cold/warm cycles certainly do that, will generate rust.

Comment: And aluminum  is by no means exempt from corrosion.

Answer (score 2):

Table saw tables are often made of cast iron, which is very susceptible to rust. I keep a plywood cover on mine at all times because a humid day can cause an orange film to form. There are products that help with that, but they need to be applied after each use.

I suggest that you try and cover or seal moisture out of the table, if not the motor and other metal components. Desiccant material can help absorb moisture in the air, but you won't reduce humidity if not in a contained space. Any exchange of outdoor air will render it ineffective.

Comment: I wax my table saw table... no rust problems.